# Consequences of running a panel VAR with 2 variables stationary at levels and one variable stationary at first difference

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, applied-econometrics

I have a trivariate Panel VAR system with the following variables:
LnGDP (Natural log of GDP)
Fiscal Expenditure (as % of GDP)
Interest rate ( in %)
LnGDP and interest rate are stationary at levels but fiscal expenditure is not. The first difference of the Fiscal Expenditure is stationary.
My first question is if I run a Panel VAR model based on the above information, what can be the future consequences?
My second question is provided the above regression is non-spurious, how do we interpret the coefficients in the model?
Thank You